# Netbeans 8.0.2 extjs project autocomplete doesnt work

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I have created html5 project in Netbeans. It uses extjs 4.0 library. But intellisense doesnt work for Ext object. Im using ext-all-debug.js version. 
How enable autocomplete for javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this file is too big. NetBeans by default won't parse JS files bigger than 1MB. You can change this behavior by using special parameters e.g. in [netbeans folder]/etc/netbeans.conf, open this file in text editor and look for `netbeans_default_options=` and append there (the whole value after = must be in double quotes):

`-J-Dnb.js.big.file.size=5145728`

and restart IDE. The result would be e.g. something like

`netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J-Dnb.js.big.file.size=5145728"`

This option forces IDE to parse files up to 5.14MB of size. See [this comment](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249338#c3) for more options